# If-statement with !== is never true PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this if-statement which appears to never be true, regardless of the value of `$xOffsetMR` and `$xOffsetSP`.

```
if ($xOffsetSP !== $xOffsetMR){
    $xOffsetSP == $xOffsetMR;
}
```

Both of them are numbers and when I check them in my console (I send them from php to javascript using ajax), I get `$xOffsetSP = 0` and `$xOffsetMR = 1170`.

Then, why does it never run the if-statement?

I know that I am in the right place of my code since i can change `$xOffsetSP` by using `$xOffsetSP = 10;` right before the statement.

Comment: What is the **exact** output of: `var_dump($xOffsetSP);` and `var_dump($xOffsetMR);` right before the if statement?

Comment: The statement on the 2nd line looks suspicious: `$xOffsetSP == $xOffsetMR;` should it be `$xOffsetSP = $xOffsetMR;`?

Comment: One problem that jumps out at me is in the body of your `if`, I'm *guessing* you mean to use `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement does work. But you are comparing (`==`) instead of assigning (`=`). Change your Statement to

```
if ($xOffsetSP !== $xOffsetMR){
            $xOffsetSP = $xOffsetMR;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a variable to a value, a single = is enough

```
if ($xOffsetSP !== $xOffsetMR){
  $xOffsetSP = $xOffsetMR;
}
```